# XMLWorkerHelper not transfer all text to the PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, ckeditor, itext

i have a problem with converting html output from creditor to my pdf.
I use the XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList method to read out the database field with the html code of the ckeditor, but not all of the content are rendered in the pdf document.

I figure out that its only affects elements of type 10 (CHUNK, if i'm right) and the content of this chunk is empty, if i print it to the console.

I reconfigure ckeditor to use `<br/>` instead of `<p>`-tags

Here an example of an html code from ckeditor:

`MS Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint)<br/>SAP<br/>Adobe Photoshop<br/>IBM SPSS Statistics<br/>EFS Survey<br/>CMS<br/>`

or

```
Kernfach: Sozialwissenschaft<br />
Note: <u><strong>1,7</strong></u><br />
<br />
Nebenfach: Rechtswissenschaft<br />
Note: <u><strong>2,3</strong></u><br />
<br />
<br />
Abschluss: <strong>Bachelor of Arts</strong><br />
<br />
Abschlussnote: <strong><u>1,9</u></strong>
```

Only the text between the tags are rendered, the other/normal text are ignored

Is this a problem of misconfiguration or do i have modify the content before pass it to the XMLWorkerHelper?

i'm thankful for tips to solve my problem.

regards
Rizzi

Comment: Have you tried putting all that into a surrounding `<html>...</html>`?

Comment: Yes. I did it this way for now. Read from database, check if there is a surrounding tag, if not, add the html tags around.